# Rooster seemingly not protecting chickens

Tags: behavior, chickens, farm-animals

So I recently got chickens and I wanted to test if the rooster would protect the hens. I let the chickens go free range and I started chasing them; the rooster went in the opposite direction of the hens. I then chased the rooster and it didn't even try to protect itself! I don't know if it's just because I'm so much bigger then the rooster or something else. Is there a reason why it didn't try to protect either the hens or itself?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Are you sure, you want a rooster, who is protecting his hens each time you come near? Maybe he didn't because you are the guy who brings the food? The roosters of my grandparent were eaten, each time they showed this behavior (and repeatedly pecked my parent, who fed them) ...

Comment: If I would need to test my rooster, I would invite someone with a leashed dog maybe. This should be more a trigger for the rooster, because the dog behaves and looks like a predator...

Comment: @Allerleirauh I tried the thing with the dog and it worked. Thank you so much. Now I don't have to kill my rooster :)

Comment: Happy, that it helps :)